# How Will I get the value of certain things from json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, visual-studio-2010

I have the following json string.

```
{
"items": {
    "642163": {
        "id": 642163,
        "nm": "AK-21699-11-Lancer-Mohammed Al Noman",
        "uid": "356307041429068",
        "ph": "+971561755362",
        "hwid": 216940,
        "pos_x": 55.3744512,
        "pos_y": 25.335552,
        "pos_z": 50,
        "pos_t": 1395383860,
        "pos_sc": 7,
        "hdop": 1.3,
        "lmsg": {
            "t": 1395383860,
            "f": 3,
            "tp": "ud",
            "pos": {
                "y": 25.335552,
                "x": 55.3744512,
                "z": 50,
                "s": 0,
                "c": 0,
                "sc": 7
            },
            "i": 0,
            "p": {
                "param179": 0,
                "param180": 1,
                "param69": 1,
                "param175": 1,
                "param182": 13,
                "hdop": 1.3,
                "pwr_ext": 12.978,
                "battery_charge": 0
            }
        },
        "param180": 1,
        "param69": 1,
        "param182": 13,
        "pwr_ext": 12.978,
        "cnm": 71869,
        "cnkb": 2400,
        "cneh": 2160,
        "client_name": "Al Kharafi",
        "access_code": "sms,sms",
        "serial_no": "2837965",
        "vreg_number": "21699",
        "instln_date": "1/14/2013",
        "vehicle_type": "car_saloon",
        "contact_ph": "branches"
    }
},
"sid": "b96c9de5b4c609f905219c20b113f712",
"count": 12,
"p_type": "hst"
}
```

I want to get the id,nm,p and pos.How will i get it in asp.net c#?

Comment: If there are more than one value like 642163 how will I do in c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the JSON.NET library. It's available via NuGet under that name.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

Now you can pull data out of your JSON string `yourText` as in the following example.

```
var token = JToken.Parse(yourText);
var nm = token["items"]["642163"]["nm"].ToObject<string>();
```

`nm` will have the value `AK-21699-11-Lancer-Mohammed Al Noman`.

Comment: If there are more than one value like 642163 how will I do in c#?

Comment: @BikashPanigrahi `token["items"]` is `IEnumerable<JToken>`. Since `items` is a JSON object, each item in the `IEnumerable<JToken>` will be a `JProperty` with `string Key` and `JToken Value`.